# Dynamically Add new columns for kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I am new to kendo grid. I need add new columns for existing Kendo Grid. Can any one help this.

```
<button id="gridButton"  onclick="AddNewColumnsForGrid()">Add New Columns</button>
<div id="grid"></div>


function AddNewColumnsForGrid()
    {

        var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
        var gridColumns = grid.columns;

                //grid.cells.add();
                //Grid.AddCells

        //$("#grid").gridColumns.push({
        //  field: NewColumn,
        //  title: "New Column",
        //});
    }
```

Comment: no such method according to my knowledge due to schema matching issue, you could re bind the grid with the new column or if the columns are static you should hide them and show later

Comment: if you look at the source on the page the kendoGrid just renders as a table.  so you can look at adding a column to a table via jquery or follow @cwishva's advice and rebind the grid

Answer (score 0):

```
add class 'k-grid-add' to a div

ex:
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                    toolbar.Template(@<div class='k-grid-add img_add'><i class="icon32 icon-orange icon-plus"></i></div>);
                })
```